How to have async calls at the creation of an ChangeNotifier in Dart / Flutter?
class FoldersProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _folders = <Directory>[];

  FoldersProvider() {
    _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible();
  }
// more code
}

_addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible is an async function.
I normally should await the Future<void> result
but I can't make the constructor async and I should still be able to instantiate it like a regular ChangeNotifier so it can still work as intended in my Flutter App.
Do you have any solution?

You can initialize the result value of _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible as a "warm-up data" before running your app. To allow smooth transition, you can use runApp twice in your main function so that you can show a widget (perhaps a loading screen) before your main app is running.
// main.dart
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const LoadingScreen());  
  await yourInitializingFunction();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Ideally, yourInitializingFunction should handle all the necessary async tasks that are required by the ChangeNotifier so that you don't need to make _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible async anymore.

See also:

Using RunApp Twice in Flutter


Instead of calling runApp twice the initializing function could be called within the initState of the LoadingScreen() or whatever view is being used as the first route of the application.

@thenry What's wrong with calling runApp twice? You can see the video I linked above that it should be common to use it to warm up data.

I'm not sure there is anything wrong with calling runApp twice, I was provided an alternative solution that followed the same principle for those who are required to keep main clean.

@thenry What's your definition for a "clean main"? Because in production app, it is common to have multiple function execution before running the main app, as packages (especially those which have platform implementations) often need functionality such as initializations in main.

@thenry Also worth noting from the documentation that calling runApp again will detach the previous root widget from the screen and attach the given widget in its place so there's nothing to worry about.

I spent a bunch of time reading various solutions for this, and calling runApp twice is by far the simplest one I've come across.

Of course, awaiting an asynchronous function's result in a constructor is impossible.
However, nothing prevents launching the execution of the function without directly waiting for the result in the constructor
I propose to you to call _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible() in FoldersProvider's constructor.
Once finished, notifyListeners() updates the UI.
On the UI side, Consumer<FoldersProvider> monitors state changes, showing a loading indicator or the folder list when ready.
Here is an overview of my proposal
class FoldersProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _folders = <Directory>[];

  FoldersProvider() {
    _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible();
  }

  List<Directory> get folders => List.unmodifiable(_folders);

  Future<void> _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible() async {
    // Simulate some asynchronous work,
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    // Simulated folders
    _folders.add(Directory('folder_1'));
    _folders.add(Directory('folder_2'));
    _folders.add(Directory('folder_3'));

    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class FoldersPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer<FoldersProvider>(
        builder: (context, foldersProvider, child) {
          if (foldersProvider.folders.isEmpty) {
             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: foldersProvider.folders.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(foldersProvider.folders[index].path),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Good answer! I'd recommend wrapping the call with unawaited() to let others (or yourself, after some time) understand that not awaiting the call was intended. Also this tells that the call should never throw. There's even a lint rule that can be enabled for this.

You can handle it using the following:

If its return type is Future<void> then no need to wait for it
but make it return just void.

OR

You can make a helper method that call and wait for it:
class FoldersProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
   final _folders = <Directory>[];

   FoldersProvider() {

     brokerCallerFunc();
   }

 void brokerCallerFunc()async=> await _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible();

 // more code
 }



Example:
void main() {
 
  Greetings();
}

class Greetings {
  
  Greetings(){
    greetUserNow();
    greetUserAfterFiveSeconds(); 
  }
  void greetUserNow()=>print('Welcome Back');
  
  void greetUserAfterFiveSeconds()async{
    
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5 ,), ()=>print('Did you wait 5 seconds? To see this message, Then Welcome Back...'));
  }
}

In the above example the constructor call two methods, one of them is asynchronous based method, and that method doesn't return anything.
It just greet the user, so there's no need to mark its return type as Future<void>, you can let it just void. Hence there's no need to await for that method.
It's strongly related to how the execution works in the asynchronous programming.
Hope it helps you.

because brookerCallerFunc is async it should return a Futur too right?

@Fractale , no, all methods are not forced to return. Hence async methods can choose whether to return or not. if it returns, the return data type must be in Future and if it's not returning anything you can mark it as void, i try to provide an example.

Since you can't apply async to the body of a constructor you could try the following:
FoldersProvider() {
_addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible().then((value) => someAction);
}

If you replace someAction with what you want to do when _addDefaultFoldersIfAccessible is complete. This value can be null.
